# How Intellij runs without any JRE installed?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellij) that Intellj is written in java,
how then it can run without any JRE installed on the machine?

Comment: Dear Jeroen i know what are JDK and JRE, i just wonder how Ide could work without any JRE (or JDK) installed on the machine, I just didn't know that it have bundled jre with it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It cannot**. Requirements clarifies that at least JDK 6 must be installed.

I guess some distributions might have it bundled but it is not the case for standard one version 12.

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ IDEA comes with JRE. Just look inside IDEA installation folder where you can find jre folder.